# C# asp.net-MVC Añadir dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, vscode, devexpress

tengo un proyecto web desarrollado en C#. Estoy intentando añadir un archivo dll que yo mismo he creado pero no consigo que funcione. Lo he añadido a las referencias y se autocompleta el código, es decir, encuentra las funciones. Sin embargo al ejecutar el servidor me sale el siguiente error:
[image: Este error me aparece a la hora de llamar a la función en la que se crea la instancia de la clase creada en el .DLL]
Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Parece como si tu dll tuviera una referencia a una version de system.runtime diferente a la que tienes cargada en tu proyecto

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.